# create incremental number from 1 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column in my dataframe where the new column is an incremental number started from 0

```
type   value
a       25
b       23
c       33
d       31
```

I expect my dataframe would be:

```
type   value   id
a       25     1
b       23     2
c       33     3
d       31     4
```

beside the `id` column, I also want to add a new column: `status_id` where from number 1 to 2 is called `foo` and from number 3 to 4 is called `bar`. I expect the full dataframe would be like:

```
type   value   id   status_id
a       25     1      foo
b       23     2      foo
c       33     3      bar
d       31     4      bar
```

How can I do this with pandas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Something like?

```
df['id'] = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
df['status_id'] = df['id'].sub(1).floordiv(2).map({0: 'foo', 1: 'bar'})
```

---

```
  type  value  id status_id
0    a     25   1       foo
1    b     23   2       foo
2    c     33   3       bar
3    d     31   4       bar
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `cut`

```
df['status_id'] = pd.cut(df.id,[0,2,4],labels=['foo','bar'])
df
  type  value  id status_id
0    a     25   1       foo
1    b     23   2       foo
2    c     33   3       bar
3    d     31   4       bar
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question,

df.insert(0, 'id', range(1, 1 + len(df)))

For the second question, are you looking at only 4 columns? If so you can insert them manually. If its two foos and two bars for x columns, you can use modulo 4 to insert them correctly.